# Generate Twitter Bootstrap Modal Dialog from PHP with variable data

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a  list of records in a table with a button to show a Bootstrap modal dialog. It's currently showing the same modal dialog for each record in the table. Here's the HTML with some sample records:

```
 <tr>
 <td><button class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" id="33926" data-target="#myModal">Review</button></td><td>Approved</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td><button class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" id="33951" data-target="#myModal">Review</button></td><td>Pending</td>
 </tr>
```

and here's the html for the modal dialog:

```
<div class="modal" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Review Job</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>This will be dynamic content from database call</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

I'm now at the point where I need to make this dynamic, so that clicking the Review button passes the value for the id attribute for the selected row to a PHP page (getRecord.php) which does a database query and returns details for the selected row to be displayed inside the modal. I'm an intermediate PHP developer but have no experience with Javascript, AJAX and jQuery which I believe I need to use to make this happen.

I haven't been able to find a template or example that shows this in action with the required steps to make this happen. Bootstrap obviously uses jQuery so no issues with using that, just have no experience with this and calling a PHP page and passing data via the button click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the data-target and data-toggle attributes. Add a class to the buttons "btn-show-details". You can bind an onclick event to your buttons using jQuery:

```
var row_id;

$('button.btn-show-details').on('click', function() {
    row_id = $(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
        url: 'getResults.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {id: row_id},
        success: function(a) {
            $('#myModalLabel').html(a.title);
            $('.modal-body').html(a.content);
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
        }
    });
});
```

In your getResults.php echo a json object like:

```
echo json_encode(array('title' => $modal_title, 'content' => $modal_content));
```

And since you have Save and Close buttons inside the modal, you will have to write additional javascript code to save the row_id in memory and handle the onclick events of those buttons. That might be like:

```
$('button.btn-close-modal').on('click', function() {
    row_id = 0;
    $('#myModalLabel, .modal-body').html('');
    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
});

$('button.btn-save-changes').on('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'saveResults.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {id: row_id, data: some_data_you_want_to_send},
        success: function(a) {
            // reload page or change stuff or show success msg
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: The modal title and body are not updating with the dynamic content that is returned from the PHP page. Is there something wrong with the syntax of the script. Here's an example of what is returned: {"title":"Modal Dialog Title","content":"modal dialog content"}

Comment: Adding dataType: 'json', to the script appears to have resolved this for now.

Comment: Oh that's right. Adding dataType: json will automatically typecast the json response into an object. If not, you would have had to use $.parseJSON() inside the success function.

Answer (score 0):

You would use Ajax to do this, a simple way of doing this is

```
<!--call script-->
<script>
    //when document is loaded and ready
    $(document).ready(function(){
        //when a user clicks on the button
        $('.btn.btn-default').on('click', function(){
            //use the id of the button that was clicked in the variable
            var reviewID = $(this).attr('id');

        //post the id to php page, and if it succeeds, return the info inside the variable 'data'
        $.post('getRecord.php', {id: reviewID}, function(data){
        //in the body of myModal, empty the previous text and use the returned value now.
            $('.modal-body').empty().text(data);
        });
    });
</script>
```